# Is there a "rails" way to post an update to a DB column using another variable to select that DB column name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Sorry for the convoluted title - what I have is a variable in my app called `@stage`, which determines how to display a set of questions on the view (e.g. one view will only show questions belonging to "stage 1" whereas clicking a button passing "stage 2" to the controller will show the questions related to stage 2.).

In order to preserve the order of the questions being asked I now need to store the "next_question_id" to show on a stage-by-stage basis. E.g. stage 1 may have reached question 3, but stage 2 is at question 7, so when someone clicks the tab for stage 1 they see the 3rd question and clicking the tab for stage 2 shows the 7th question. In order to do this I'm going to add fields `stage_1_next_question_id` and `stage_2_next_question_id` etc.

When the user answers the question I'll make a callback to update the relevant column with the latest question to ask in each stage. Obviously I could do that with some conditional logic, e.g.:

```
if @stage == "stage 1"
 self.stage_1_next_question_id = question.id
elsif @stage == "stage 2"
 self.stage_2_next_question_id = question.id
etc etc
```

But this seems very clunky and not very DRY as a way of posing. I'm hoping there's a way of taking the name of @stage and using that to define the attribute to update, e.g.

```
field_name = '@stage.to_s' + '_next_question_id'
self.field_name = question.id
```

Or something similar to this which would dynamically use the @stage variable to decide which of my attributes it was going to update.

I also want to use the @stage variable when retrieving the questions so I get the next_question_id from the correct column.

Is this possible in Rails? Is there a best practice for implementing this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this using the `read_attribute(col_name)` and `write_attribute(col_name, value)` methods where col_name is the name of your column as a symbol or string.

More generally, you can use `<object>.send("name_of_function")` to dynamically send messages to methods in Ruby. In other words, `"foo".send("length")` would return 3.

However, I'm trying to think about how what you're proposing is necessary. Is `stage` a model? If so, shouldn't each stage have a `next_question_id` and `previous_column_id`? In other words, the stage "number" shouldn't need to be in the column/variable name in the first place.

Comment: Thanks - in this case the question has_many sale_qualifiers, which each has_one answer. What I'm doing is attributing a question to a stage and giving it a next_question_id (depending upon whether it's just a question with e.g. a date as an answer, or whether it's a yes/no answer) and using that to drive a state machine. The stage is used by the view to show questions according to whether they're about "budget" or "need" or some other stage, and I need to ensure when someone clicks "budget" it shows the next "budget" related question rather than a "need" related question.

Comment: Also - I'm getting NoMethodError: private method `write_attribute' called for #<object> errors when trying to use write_attribute